# Django forms: Accessing cleaned_data in clean() - not working?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

Ok so I'm trying to write the clean() in a forms class.

**Issue: when accessing the values: name, age, height from the clean_data dict it is not returning the
field values.**

Am I accessing the dictionary correctly? because the if condition isn't working correctly

```
class PersonForms(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Your Name")
    height = forms.DecimalField(help_text="height..")
    age = forms.IntegerField(help_text="age:")

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'height')

    # Fields are validated in their own field_clean() method.clean() method is to validate any combination or
    # multiple fields with values relating to one another.
    def clean(self):
        print("clean...$$")

        # run the standard clean method first - this ensures
        # The ModelForm.clean() method sets a flag that makes the model validation step validate the uniqueness of
        # model fields that are marked as unique, unique_together or unique_for_date | month | year.
        cleaned_data = super(PersonForms, self).clean()

        # once the parent's clean function valids data - access fields via cleaned_data dictionary
        name = cleaned_data.get("name")
        age = cleaned_data.get("age")
        height = cleaned_data.get("height")

        if "max" not in name or age > 13:
            print("*************** name", name)
            raise ValidationError(_("Err, type %(value) as name or age %(age) invalid"),
                                  params={'value': name, 'age': age}, code='invalid1')
```

Comment: explain please. where?

Comment: you need return cleaned_data.

Comment: just try like this `name = cleaned_data["name"]`